# Polymorphism in C#. Explain output

Tags: c#

I expected output `C` in this program. But real result is `A`.
Please, explain why program prints `A`.

```
class A 
{
    public virtual void  say() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("A");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public new virtual void say() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("B");
    }
}

class C : B 
{
    public override void say() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("C");
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        A a = new C ();
        a.say();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you created [new](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) virtual method `say()` in the class `B`.
This new method hides original method `A.say()`, so in the class `C` you overriden this new method `B.say()` but not the `A.say()`.

And since you declared your object as `A`

```
A a = new C ();
```

the old `A.say()` method is called.

Answer (score 2):

You're not overriding the say method in Class B, which is the sub class of Class C.

```
   public new virtual void say()
```

In the above line, you're hiding the say method.  [Look at the new modifier here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx)